# Java Swing/AWT Component Access From Another Class

Tags: java, swing, swt, access-modifiers

I am writing a sample application with [*Sakila Sample Database*](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/sakila.html) for some experience. I am using eclipse/windowsbuilder for GUI. I have 3 class; VALIDATION to check component values, CONNECTOR to complete SQL queries and MAIN class which one has components. My problem is, I can not access components from another class. All of them in the same package access modifiers public for the classes.

I have tried below one;

```
 public class Connector{

    MovieDB mdb;

    public Connector(MovieDB m){

        mdb = m;
    }
 }

 public class MovieDB extends JFrame {

    Connector db = new Connector(this);
 }
```

But still I can not access components and I m in depression pls help:)

Comment: GUI inter-object communication is the same as inter object communication for any other non-GUI program, often using design patterns if need be. For example: [sending-messages-between-two-jpanel-objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053283/sending-messages-between-two-jpanel-objects/7054114#7054114)

Comment: Nice example [schema](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/images/sakila-schema.png).

Comment: Thank you Hovercraft solution was simple, I just needed to access variables so I took below part from your code block;

      public String getNorthFieldText() {
          return northField.getText();
       }

Answer (score 2):

Check the access modifier of the components and verify that they are not private.