# Java another Static/Non-Static issue

Tags: java, static-methods

Ok, using Eclipse IDE and getting tripped up on the static/non static issue.  I think I understand it, but not completely, here is the code.

First Part, mostly created with the swing UI builder. *edited out comments/imports*

```
public class Screen {

private JFrame frame;
public JLabel lblNewLabel;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Screen window = new Screen();
                window.frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

public Screen() {
    initialize();
}

void initialize() {
    XListener listenItem = new XListener("Woot"); // creates listen object

    frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(193, 154, 56, 16);
    frame.getContentPane().add(lblNewLabel);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.setBounds(163, 73, 97, 25);
    frame.getContentPane().add(btnNewButton);
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(listenItem); // attaches it to listen object
}
void changeLabel(String setString) {
    lblNewLabel.setText(setString);
}
}
```

Second part is the listener class

```
// creates class for listen item
public class XListener implements ActionListener {
    String foo;
    XListener(String setString) {
        foo = setString;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent btnNewButton) {
        **Screen.changeLabel(foo);**
    }
}
```

It complains that cannot make a static reference to the non-static method changeLabel(String) from the type Screen.  Yet, if I use window, in place of Screen, it cannot find the object.  This has me extremely confused.  The way I understand the code, is the main method creates a Screen object, named window, which when initialized also creates a XListener object.  Why does it consider the actionPerformed method to be static?  I know there is something fundamental I am missing, and I have been following the java 'trails' and just don't get it.

Comment: for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053283/sending-messages-between-two-jpanel-objects/7054114#7054114,

Answer (score 4):

You should pass in a reference to the `Screen` object you want to affect when the action occurs:

```
// creates class for listen item
public class XListener implements ActionListener {
    String foo;
    Screen myScreen;

    XListener(String setString, Screen scr) {
        foo = setString;
        myScreen = scr;
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent btnNewButton) {
        myScreen.changeLabel(foo);
    }
}
```

Then, initialize your listener like so:

```
XListener listenItem = new XListener("Woot", this);
```

You have to do this because the `changeLabel()` method is an instance method on the `Screen` class, but you're attempting to access it like a `static` method. By having access to the correct `Screen` instance, you can call the method properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your XListener class needs an object to call it on. Calling `Screen.changeLabel(foo)` will try to call a static method on the class Screen. You need a Screen object passed into your XListener class.

```
public class XListener implements ActionListener {
    String foo;
    Screen myScreen; // added
    XListener(String setString, Screen theScreen) {
        foo = setString;
        myScreen= theScreen; // added
    }
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent btnNewButton) {
        screen.changeLabel(foo); // fixed
    }
}
```

Then change your init method:

```
void initialize() {
    XListener listenItem = new XListener("Woot",this); // creates listen object

    // rest below
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `changeLabel` is an instance method, yet you are trying to invoke it using the static method syntax of <Class Name>.<Method Name>. You need to obtain a reference to the `Screen` object in order to invoke this method.

One way to resolve it might be to pass such an object to the listener's constructor, like so:

```
XListener(Screen screen, String setString)
    ...
    this.screen=screen;
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

`window` is a *local* variable within the `run` method within the anonymous `Runnable` subclass created in `main`. You certainly can't refer to that within `XListener.actionPerformed`.

Java isn't considering the `actionPerformed` method to be static - it's saying `changeLabel` is non-static but you're trying to *access* it as if it's static *from* `actionPerformed`, here:

```
Screen.changeLabel(foo);
```

It's irrelevant whether `actionPerformed` is static or not - the point is that you need to have a reference to an *instance* of `Screen` in order to call the `changeLabel` method. Otherwise it's like asking "How tall is the person?" - it doesn't make sense unless you specify *which* person you're talking about.

If you're finding static/non-static confusing, I would *strongly* advise you to leave user interfaces well alone for the moment. Write some simple *console* applications which create some objects, call methods on them etc. Get comfortable with the language, and ideally some of the core libraries (e.g. collections and IO). *Then* you'll be able to enter the sometimes-daunting world of user interfaces and at least know what's going on at the *language* level.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a non-static method called changeLabel but then you try access it off the class, i.e. Screen.changeLabel() which you cannot do since it is not a static method. You first need to instantiate Screen and then call this method off the instance that you have created (or pass through an instance, etc, the point is non-static methods need be be accessed off an Object, not directly off a Class).

Comment: Depending on what changeLabel() does, you may need to make some other changes to screen in order to make this method static though

Comment: making changeLabel static will not help anything unless everything else in the Screen class was static too, which would be a tad silly.

Comment: agreed, would be silly but it would compile. I'm not advocating that solution, just saying that it is an option