# JTable value from another JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jtable, access-modifiers

I have `JTable` and I want to set value at specific cell from another frame. When I try to do it, I get null pointer exception. I changed the modifiers and removed the exception, but still can't set the value.

Please guys help

```
public ChequeVoucher(int id,int row){
       try {
           String str = get_bank_name(id);
           System.out.println(str); 

           table.getModel().setValueAt(str,row,5);
           table.getModel().setValueAt(id,row,4);
       } catch (SQLException f) {
       }
       setBank(id,row); 
    }

public void setBank(int id,int row){
    try {
            String str = get_bank_name(id);
            table.getModel().setValueAt(str,row,5);
        } catch (SQLException f) {
        }
    }
```

The chequevoucher is my constructor and this piece of code is good until this

```
 table.getModel().setValueAt(str,row,5);
```

and the `JFrame` I get the value from is

```
   table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
       public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
         int row = table.getSelectedRow();
         int col = table.getSelectedColumn();
         String str_id = (String)GetID(row,0); 
         int id = Integer.parseInt(str_id);
         ChequeVoucher CV = new ChequeVoucher(id,row); 
         setVisible(false);
        }
     });
```

The access modifiers wasn't static so I get the following error stack

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at client.ChequeVoucher.(ChequeVoucher.java:215) 
at client.popupBanks$3.mouseClicked(popupBanks.java:130) 
at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:253) 
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6292) 
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3267) 
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6054) 
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2041) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4652) 
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2099) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482) 
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4577) 
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4247) 
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4168) 
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2085) 
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2478) 
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4482) 
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:644) 
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:85) 
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:603) 
at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(EventQueue.java:601) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87) 
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98) 
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:617) 
at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:615) 
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) 
at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87) 
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:614) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161) 
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)
```

When I made the modifiers static, I get no exceptions but nothing happens and I can't listen to the `JTable` anymore

```
 case KeyEvent.VK_F5:
     switch(col){
         case 4:
         //show the banks 
         popupBanks pB = new popupBanks(row); 
         pB.setVisible(true);

         break;
  }
```

Sorry for the previous unclear post

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7053283/sending-messages-between-two-jpanel-objects , answer by @Hovercraft Full Of Eels, that would be similair issue for me

Comment: @mKorbel
thanks but this is not what I am looking for because I think my main problem with the JTable

Comment: then change MouseListener to the http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/listselectionlistener.html

Comment: Please don't swallow exceptions.

Comment: which is line 215? why do think being static or not has anything to do with your problem?

Comment: line 215 :table.getModel().setValueAt(str,row,5);
and changing it to static stops the exception

Comment: then something is wrong in the code you'r not showing - your setup is wrong. Step back and learn about objects, classes and accessor scope..

Comment: I don't know were is the wrong setup and still have the problem and I've traced the App the problem from setValueAt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ChequeVoucher method you call is definitely a constructor and at this point, your table is null unless you specify its value with something else. You can add the table in your constructor which will solve the problem.
The best solution would be creating a ChequeVoucher with your JTable as constructor parameter and doing everything else with methods.